# Is using DI with protected properties on base class a bad practice?

Tags: .net, dependency-injection

I am currently facing a particular situation. I have this context:

A class (`A`) is inheriting from another (`B`) which is implementing an interface (`I1`). A is also implementing another interface (`I2`).

```cs
public class A : B, I2 {}
public class B : I1 {}
```

`B` implements all methods described in `I1`, that are used by `A`. But `A` has to implement a method from `I2`, which can't be inside `I1` because it's not `I1`'s purpose.

The thing is, the body of `A`'s implementation of `I1`'s method is similar to `B`'s implementation of `I1`'s methods. These similarities are the use of objects injected in `B`.

Here is how does the injection look like:

```cs
public class B : I1 {
    private readonly DI1 _di1;
    private readonly DI2 _di2;

    public B(DI1 di1, DI2 di2) 
    {
        this._di1 = di1;
        this._di2 = di2;
    }
}
```

```cs
public class A : B, I2 {
    public A(DI1 di1, DI2 di2)
        : base(di1, di2)
    {
    }
}
```

As I also need `DI1` and `DI2` in `A` I would like to know if there is any possible issue by changing `B`'s fields accessors from `private` to `protected`? So that I can use them in `A`, without having to create new fields in `A` that would be the exact same thing than `B`'s fields.

It may be as simple as a "regular" protected field in inheritance. But as we are here playing with DI I was wondering if it could cause any issue ? I feel like it won't, but I want to make myself sure about this.

I had a look in [Microsoft's guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection-guidelines), but saw nothing related to this.

Comment: should not be a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's certainly okay to use the protected modifier. It doesn't matter if the fields are injected; the access modifiers used should not affect the expected behavior of DI.